# Simple TimeStamp class in Python

Tags: python, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel, micropython

For a project I'm working on we need a basic time holder class.  This is written in CircuitPython, which is a stripped down version of CPython that's missing a number of libraries, including the whole datetime library.

The class definition is as follows.  Note that `TimeDelta` is very similar, it also holds a second and day count, but is meant to represent a duration rather than a single point in time.  Thus a different class for the different semantic meaning.

`__hms_to_secs()` and `__ymd_to_days()` do exactly what their names suggest they ought to.

```
class TimeStamp:
    def __init__(self, year = 2000, month = 1, day = 1, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0):
        self.seconds = __hms_to_secs(hours, minutes, seconds)
        self.days = __ymd_to_days(year, month, day)
        self.normalize()

    def normalize(self):
        if self.seconds < 0 or self.seconds >= 86400:
            day_error = self.seconds // 86400
            self.seconds -= day_error * 86400
            self.days += day_error
        return self

    def __add__(self, rhs)
        return (TimeStamp(self.days + rhs.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs.seconds) if isinstance(rhs, TimeDelta) else TimeDelta(self.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs)).normalize()

    def __sub__(self, rhs)
        return (TimeDelta(self.days - rhs.days, 0, 0, self.seconds - rhs.seconds) if isinstance(rhs, TimeDelta) else TimeDelta(self.days, 0, 0, self.seconds - rhs)).normalize()
```

The one thing I'm curious about is the `normalize()` method.  By both modifying `self` and returning it as well, it allows both

```
    time_stamp.normalize()
```

and

```
    return temporary_time_stamp.normalize()
```

to work like you'd expect.  But as a relative newcomer to Python I have no idea if this is considered good style.  Also observations on `__add__()` and `__sub__()` are welcome.  Is there a preference for longer "do it all" statements, or for breaking them up into two or more bite sized lines?  The intention is to offer two overloads, either adding a `TimeDelta` or a raw count of seconds.

As a 40 year career C/C++ programmer, overloading based on parameter type is second nature to me.  I miss it a lot in Python, which can't do it due to the fact it's duck-typed.  So I've taken to doing the overload resolution at run-time.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the code in your question after it has been answered.  In this case, I'm going to edit the answer to match, since that's straightforward, but in future please don't do that.

Answer (score 8):

First, I want to point out that [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) exist, which means a day is not necessarily guaranteed to be exactly 86400 seconds. If you're aware of this and have determined your use case does not require you to account for it, that is fine, but I'm still pointing it out in case you weren't aware of it

Speaking of 86400, it might be nice to have that broken out into a constant with a descriptive name like `SECONDS_PER_DAY`

Beyond that, I'd argue that `normalize` is a method that users will not want to care about at all:

If we do not expect users to manually modify an existing `TimeStamp`'s or `TimeDelta`'s `seconds` and `days` values, we are already providing only normalized values -- they get normalized as part of their initialization, and never become un-normalized

If we *do* expect users to manually modify existing values, I still don't think keeping the value normalized should be their responsibility -- rather, I would suggest that normalization be guaranteed as part of the modification. [The built-in `property` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) could help with that, if CircuitPython supports it

Either way, I don't think we should be thinking of `normalize` as part of our interface, when we can instead make every part of our interface provide only normalized values

On a related note, the `normalize` calls in `__add__` and `__sub__` are kind of redundant -- freshly created timestamps and timedeltas are already normalized, and since we don't modify them between creation and return, normalizing them again does nothing

Finally, while in-line `if`s have their uses, they can be a bit cumbersome to read, and `if`/`else` blocks are usually preferred. I might rewrite `__add__` (and `__sub__`) closer to

```
def __add__(self, rhs):
    if isinstance(rhs, TimeDelta):
        return TimeStamp(self.days + rhs.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs.seconds)
    else:
        return TimeDelta(self.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs)
```

Alternatively, I might go with the "ask forgiveness, not permission" approach that's common in the Python community, and end up with something akin to

```
def __add__(self, rhs):
    try:
        return TimeStamp(self.days + rhs.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs.seconds)
    except AttributeError:
        return TimeDelta(self.days, 0, 0, self.seconds + rhs)
```

### Edit

My intuition is that `some_timestamp + 3` should be the same kind of operation as `some_timestamp + TimeDelta(seconds=3)`, but the latter returns a `TimeStamp` while the former returns a `TimeDelta`. I suspect that might not be intentional - is it? If it is, I feel like it's not obvious what that operation, and the resulting `TimeDelta`, represents, and it may be good to clarify that

Comment: `normalize()` should probably be renamed to `__normalize()` because the external API need not allow direct modification of the members.  To change a `TimeStamp` use a `TimeDelta`.  As an extension, renaming the members to `__days` and  `__seconds` has merit.  As for the calls to `normalize()` in `__add__()` and `__sub__()` the use case is subtracting a `TimeDelta` holding 23 hours from a `TimeStamp` representing `2020/6/8T12:23:34`.  In the absence of the `normalize()` call, that would leave the `TimeStamp` with a seconds value that's out of range.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware of leap seconds, the conscious decision to "ignore" them has been made.  The necessity here is something that provides accuracy to within a second or two, not "to the millisecond" accuracy.  In the long term, this will ping an NTP server every few hours, which should silently handle the problem.  As long as it's only ever a single second change, we will gracefully handle it, either a second simply goes missing in action or more commonly gets duplicated. Neither of those cases will break the system.

Comment: @dgnuff But `__add__` creates a new `TimeStamp`, which means it gets normalized by the `normalize` call in `__init__` before the `normalize` calls in `__add__`/`__sub__` can be reached, no?

Comment: I'm aware of the "ask forgiveness" principle in Python, I don't agree with it.  Just about every other language takes the view that exceptions are not to be used for flow control, since doing so can introduce all sorts of subtle bugs.  In this case, use of the exception pattern allows the addition of any class that has `days` and `seconds` members.  Any class whatsoever, including as it happens `TimeStamp` itself.  The only legal RHS for addition to a `TimeStamp` is a `TimeDelta`.  The if pattern enforces this, the exception pattern doesn't.

Comment: Good point about the unnecessary `normalize()`, removing it helps improve code readability

Comment: Most languages that discourage use of exceptions in the happy(ish) path do so for _performance_ reasons that don't apply to Python, rather than to ensure functional correctness.  You can disagree all you like, but it always pays to use the language's established idioms if you want to work with others.  If you want to constrain argument types, use annotations (but be aware that duck-typing is the established Python idiom, so you're going against the grain there, too).

Comment: @TobySpeight In most of the discussions I've seen, performance has very little to do with it.  The argument usually revolves around the fact that an exception is a non-local goto.  Which in turn makes the code fragile.  Consider the following scenario,for `__add__()`  Rather than the simple work in the `try` clause, assume it does something far more complex, that just happens to throw the very exception we're catching.  You've now got a nightmare on your hands: it'll try the `catch` clause, and that will of course fail because the RHS was actually a valid TimeStamp. ...

Comment: @TobySpeight So that will throw another exception, and the original one that caused the problem has been completely lost.  Result: a very hard to debug problem.  And what about the case I mentioned above.  I want to be able to add a `TimeDelta` to a `TimeStamp` but I don't want to be able to add two `TimeStamps`  If they both use `days` and `seconds` as their members, the exception flow can't distinguish the two.  So it's merrily add a pair of `TimeStamp`s together producing a meaningless result.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's more fragile here than depending on `instanceof` to guess whether `days` should be added or not.  I think that's going to remain a subjective judgement, though.